# Get id that is not present in object array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have one array and one object that contains array of ids (permission objects).

now i want to get the ids that are not present in the object can anyone help me with the logic?

```
 id: [2,3,4]
 object = [0:
 Permission: {id: 2},
 1: Permission: {id: 3}
 ]
 result: [4]
```

Comment: If you need the above one as Object then I believe the Object Structure is incorrect. Please confirm the below: 
id: [2,3,4];

object = [{0: {Permission: {id: 2}}, 1: {Permission: {id: 3}}} ]; // is this structure what you need?

Comment: yes thats what I need and sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter(). Example:

```js
var id = [2,3,4];

var object = [
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
 ];

objectIds = object.map(myObj => myObj.id);
idNotIn = id.filter(myId => !objectIds.includes(myId));

console.log('objectIds: '+ objectIds);
console.log('idNotIn: '+ idNotIn);
```

Or in a single line of code:

```
idNotIn = id.filter(myId => !object.map(myObj => myObj.id).includes(myId));
```